# d3.js how to calculate new endpoints for each line with a distance of X from node center

Tags: math, d3.js

I have a force directed graph and I'd like to adjust the endpoints of the lines to be 30px from the node center. I believe I need to modify the tick function to calculate the new coordinates for x1,y1 and x2,y2 but I haven't touched geometry in a long time and can't seem to figure out the right equation to accomplish this.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Update...**

So I managed to do this using the following (thanks to a friend). Slight caveat, this has a bug with the line is vertical. If anyone has a more efficient way I'd love the help.

```
    function distance(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
      y = y2 - y1;
      x = x2 - x1;
      return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    }

    function calc_slope(d) {
      x1 = d.source.x;
      y1 = d.source.y;
      x2 = d.target.x;
      y2 = d.target.y;

      return (y2-y1)/parseFloat(x2-x1);
    }

    function calc_constant(slope, x, y) {
      return (y - (slope * x));
    }

    function calc_y(slope, constant, x){
      return (slope * x) + constant;
    }

    function adjusted_source_x(d, adjustment_size) {
      x1 = d.source.x;
      y1 = d.source.y;
      x2 = d.target.x;
      y2 = d.target.y;

      if (distance(x1,y1,x2,y2) < (2 * adjustment_size)){
        return x1;
      }

      if (x1 == x2){
        return x1;
      }

      slope = calc_slope(d);
      constant = calc_constant(slope, x1, y1);

      if (x1 < x2){
        x1_prime = x1 + adjustment_size;
        y1_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x1_prime);

        while (distance(x1,y1,x1_prime,y1_prime) > adjustment_size){
          x1_prime = x1_prime - 1;
          y1_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x1_prime);
        }
        return x1_prime;
      }
      else{
        x1_prime = x1 - adjustment_size;
        y1_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x1_prime);

        while (distance(x1,y1,x1_prime,y1_prime) > adjustment_size){
          x1_prime = x1_prime + 1;
          y1_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x1_prime);
        }
        return x1_prime; 
      }
    }

    function adjusted_source_y(d, adjustment_size) {
      x1 = d.source.x;
      y1 = d.source.y;
      x2 = d.target.x;
      y2 = d.target.y;

      if (distance(x1,y1,x2,y2) < (2 * adjustment_size)){
        return y1;
      }

      if (x1 == x2){
        if(y1 < y2){
          return (y1 + adjustment_size)
        }
        else {
          return (y1 - adjustment_size)
        }
      }

      slope = calc_slope(d);
      constant = calc_constant(slope, x1, y1);

      if (x1 < x2){
        x1_prime = x1 + adjustment_size;
        y1_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x1_prime);

        while (distance(x1,y1,x1_prime,y1_prime) > adjustment_size){
          x1_prime = x1_prime - 1;
          y1_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x1_prime);
        }
        return y1_prime;
      }
      else{
        x1_prime = x1 - adjustment_size;
        y1_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x1_prime);

        while (distance(x1,y1,x1_prime,y1_prime) > adjustment_size){
          x1_prime = x1_prime + 1;
          y1_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x1_prime);
        }
        return y1_prime; 
      }
    }

    function adjusted_target_x(d, adjustment_size) {
      x1 = d.source.x;
      y1 = d.source.y;
      x2 = d.target.x;
      y2 = d.target.y;

      if (distance(x1,y1,x2,y2) < (2 * adjustment_size)){
        return x2;
      }

      if (x1 == x2){
        return x2;
      }

      slope = calc_slope(d);
      constant = calc_constant(slope, x1, y1);

      if (x2 < x1){
        x2_prime = x2 + adjustment_size;
        y2_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x2_prime);

        while (distance(x2,y2,x2_prime,y2_prime) > adjustment_size){
          x2_prime = x2_prime - 1;
          y2_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x2_prime);
        }
        return x2_prime;
      }
      else{
        x2_prime = x2 - adjustment_size;
        y2_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x2_prime);

        while (distance(x2,y2,x2_prime,y2_prime) > adjustment_size){
          x2_prime = x2_prime + 1;
          y2_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x2_prime);
        }
        return x2_prime; 
      }
    }

    function adjusted_target_y(d, adjustment_size) {
      x1 = d.source.x;
      y1 = d.source.y;
      x2 = d.target.x;
      y2 = d.target.y;

      if (distance(x1,y1,x2,y2) < (2 * adjustment_size)){
        return y2;
      }

      if (x1 == x2){
        if(y2 < y1){
          return (y2 + adjustment_size)
        }
        else {
          return (y2 - adjustment_size)
        }
      }

      slope = calc_slope(d);
      constant = calc_constant(slope, x1, y1);

      if (x2 < x1){
        x2_prime = x2 + adjustment_size;
        y2_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x2_prime);

        while (distance(x2,y2,x2_prime,y2_prime) > adjustment_size){
          x2_prime = x2_prime - 1;
          y2_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x2_prime);
        }
        return y2_prime;
      }
      else{
        x2_prime = x2 - adjustment_size;
        y2_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x2_prime);

        while (distance(x2,y2,x2_prime,y2_prime) > adjustment_size){
          x2_prime = x2_prime + 1;
          y2_prime = calc_y(slope, constant, x2_prime);
        }
        return y2_prime; 
      }
    }

    function tick() {
      node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});
      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return adjusted_source_x(d, 45); })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return adjusted_source_y(d, 45); })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return adjusted_target_x(d, 45); })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return adjusted_target_y(d, 45); });
    }
```

Comment: If you know the positions of the nodes, there's no need to use the force layout.

Comment: It might be simpler to achieve this by using the `linkDistance` property of the layout. Check the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkDistance) and this simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/GLKyM/) borrowed from another question.

Comment: @Lars, unfortunately I don't know the position of the nodes until the graph is first run. The data supporting this graph gets updated frequently and new nodes are entered with the force applied. When a person interacts with a node it the have the option to lock it in place to make it persistent across reloads.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes, thank you for the suggestion but the **linkDistance** property only allows you to adjust the total distance of a line, not where the endpoints of the line are relative to the source and target node centers. I wish there was a built in property for this.